# Implicit intent - No suitable recipient

Tags: android, android-intent

What would happen if there are no available applications (satisfying the intent criteria) that can take up a particular implicit intent ?.

If there are multiple apps available that can take up, a choice is given to the user..I am interested in the other way around.

Can anyone provide their input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ActivityNotFoundException will be thrown, that's why if you are not using a system app, you should always put your intent calls in try catchs

Answer (score 0):

From memory I think an "ActivityNotFoundException" is thrown when you attempt to start the activity e.g.

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse( "market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
try {
   startActivity(marketIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
   // Google market not installed...
}
```